# how to check already groupname is allow or not

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have form in that I have to check existing username. If username already exist then not allow to submit form. For that I have used ajax to check from submit. In this code It return true and instead of returning false it always return true and submit the form.

```
function lks()
            {  
                var groupname = document.getElementById('groupname').value;
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                     if(xmlhttp.responseText=="already"){
                           alert("Groupname Already in use");
                           return false;
                     }
                }
            };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "checkgroupname.php?groupname=" + groupname, true);
    xmlhttp.send();                    
            }
```

and my checkgrouname.php file is as below

```
<?php
session_start();
$loginuser = $_SESSION['username'];
$groupname = $_GET['groupname'];
$checkgroupname = trim(`sudo grep -w $groupname /home/$loginuser/.groupmanagement`);
if($checkgroupname!=NULL){
    echo json_encode("already");
}
else{
    echo json_encode("allow");
}
?>
```

Please tell any alternative method if possible.

Comment: U r not exiting your command

Comment: what is the meaninig?